# i can't use javascript code with bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, struts2

I use some Bootstrap template  with my struts2 applicaion :

http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/adminlte

that uses these files :

https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/tree/master/js/AdminLTE

I want to integrate some javascript code to my jsp page :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//javascript code     
    });

</script>
```

the new code does not work with the use of these files:

```
 <!-- AdminLTE App -->
        <script src="<c:url value="page/js/AdminLTE/app.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
        <script src="<c:url value="page/js/AdminLTE/dashboard.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However  the script works fine if I not call them in my code; how can i resolve this problem please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a jQuery conflict. Try using the noConflict in jQuery like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then your script will look like this:

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();    

$j(document).ready(function(){

//javascript code     
});

</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no,the new code doesn't work, and I lose the functioning of javascript files on my template, I want to keep the functioning of the both of them ? –  lilyana 23 mins ago

Comment: do you get any exact error? can you post that in here? more info would help to answer this better!

Comment: Could you post a link to your page?