# Jquery not functioning in bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've using bootstrap template for my project https://almsaeedstudio.com/.
I've also add i few jquery script but it not working.

I've have tried to use this method but also not working. 
[i can't use javascript code with bootstrap template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050493/i-cant-use-javascript-code-with-bootstrap-template)

This is my html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="view-more">Large</button>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view-more").click(function(){
        alert("Test");
});
</script>
```

Comment: One of those functions is missing a closing brace and bracket! `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the closing `});`

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view-more").click(function(){
        alert("Test");
    });
});
```